# Cross browser key event handler in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm using the M1 release and have written a key handler that looks like this:

```
void _onKeyPress(KeyboardEvent e) {
  switch (e.keyIdentifier) {
    case KeyName.UP:
    case KeyName.LEFT:
      e.preventDefault();
      prev();
      break;

    case "U+0020": // FIXME Must be a better way, or?
    case KeyName.DOWN:
    case KeyName.RIGHT:
      e.preventDefault();
      next();
      break;
  }
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, but not in FF or IE. There must be better way to handle the space bar and still keep it in one switch, right? I know that I can look at other fields to get space, but that is not a good alternative either (since then I would split the code into two switch statements.) Any way, the issue with it not working in FF and IE is worse. If I rewrite to use `keyCode` instead it works fine on all browsers.

```
void _onKeyPress(KeyboardEvent e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:
    case 37:
      e.preventDefault();
      prev();
      break;

    case 32:
    case 40:
    case 39:
      e.preventDefault();
      next();
      break;
  }
}
```

My issue is that I can't find the constants for the virtual key codes. Am I doing something wrong? What is the best way to handle key events cross browser compatible in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, the other answer, this [source code](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-web-components/blob/master/example/todomvc/item.html), and this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5540) (which you should star), here are my recommendations:

- Use keyCode.
- Don't be afraid to use use if/else if instead of a switch statement if you need to. JavaScript doesn't have optimized switch statements anyway.
- Until [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5540) gets fixed, you should probably just create your own constants.

**Updated**: This has been [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5540).

Comment: Thanks jj, I'm not afraid of if/else but you must agree that you lose clarity compared to switch. I will star the issue :-)

Comment: Thanks for starring it, Tobias :) Yes, I agree that you lose clarity compared to switch.

Comment: This has been fixed! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar problem to this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4269). Apparently, the KeyIdentifier returns null on Firefox.

By the way, instead of "U+0020" you could use [KeyName.SPACEBAR](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/KeyName.html#SPACEBAR)

Comment: Yes, but I think that it has to do with the DOM in FF and IE (I think it is realted to [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680830). I hope there is some thinking behind the design of the dart api to do this in a nice way. But it may also be that they wait out the DOM implementations...

But no `KeyName.SPACEBAR` does not work I tried that and it is a different constant. Possibly a bug, I'm not sure.